# Resize column of datatable on click of right border of perticular column header

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, datatables

I'm tring to resize table coloumn on click of right border of column header but i can not figure out how to do it.

I have used `ColReorderWithResize.js` but its adjusting size by attributes not on click of right border of column header

```
$('#example').dataTable({
                    "scrollY": 400,
                    "scrollX": true,
                    "bPaginate": false,
                    "bFilter": false,
                    "bInfo": false,
                    "responsive": true,
                    "bAutoWidth": true,
                    "sDom": '<"H"lCf>t"H"<"F"iTp>',
                    "aoColumns": [{'sWidth': "30%"},
                        {'sWidth': "30%"},
                        {'sWidth': "30%"},
                        {'sWidth': "30%"},
                        {'sWidth': "30%"},
                        {'sWidth': "30%"},
                        {'sWidth': "30%"},
                        {'sWidth': "30%"},
                        {'sWidth': "30%"}
                    ],
                });
```

I write this jquery for this but it didnt work properly

```
     $('#example').find('thead th').bind("click.MyDT", function(event){
    if ($(event.target).css('cursor') === 'col-resize'){
        event.cancelBubble = true;
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
});
```

please give me proper solution for this.

Comment: You can add the onclick event to resize. it is not going to work automatically.

like $('#example thead').click(function() {
code to resize
})

Comment: what version of jquery you are using??

Comment: jquery-1.11.1.min.js